# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory in JUnit test

Tags: java, maven, junit, entitymanager

an application is giving me errors when trying to build it - it stops on a test, which just creates EntityManagerFactory. I also have a main method with some code which persists entities into database, but running it without tests works alright.

Here's a test output

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.205 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(sk.matejkvassay.musiclibrary.AlbumDaoImplTest)  Time elapsed: 1.135 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: TestPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at sk.matejkvassay.musiclibrary.AlbumDaoImplTest.test(AlbumDaoImplTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:524)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:271)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
    ... 45 more
```

test itself

```
public class AlbumDaoImplTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestPU");
        assertNotNull(emf);
    }
}
```

main method

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Album album1=new Album();
        album1.setCommentary("Commentary commentary commentary.");
        album1.setTitle("Album title");

        Genre genre1=new Genre();
        genre1.setName("Genre name");
        genre1.setDescription("Genre commentary.");

        Song song1=new Song();
        Song song2=new Song();
        Song song3=new Song();

        song1.setAlbum(album1);
        song1.setBitrate(320);
        song1.setCommentary("Song commentary.");
        song1.setPositionInAlbum(1);
        song1.setTitle("Song title.");

        song2.setAlbum(album1);
        song2.setBitrate(320);
        song2.setCommentary("Song commentary.");
        song2.setPositionInAlbum(2);
        song2.setTitle("Song title.");

        song3.setAlbum(album1);
        song3.setBitrate(320);
        song3.setCommentary("Song commentary.");
        song3.setPositionInAlbum(2);
        song3.setTitle("Song title.");


        HashSet<Song>songs= new HashSet<Song>();
        songs.add(song1);
        songs.add(song2);
        songs.add(song3);
        album1.setSongs(songs);


        em.persist(genre1);
        em.persist(song1);
        em.persist(song2);
        em.persist(song3);
        em.persist(album1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/ persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/ persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="TestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="testUser"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="testUser123"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/musicLibraryTestDB"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sk.matejkvassay</groupId>
    <artifactId>MusicLibrary</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MusicLibrary</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>       
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.1.1</version>           
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided stack trace you are missing a dependency for bean validation.

Try adding hibernate-validator as a dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Wish I asked earlier, spent more time on this than I'd like to admit.